# Laravel - how to remove element from the view for the specific page

Tags: laravel

I have a link in my navigation top bar that I would like to remove when the user is on the registration page. I thought I would be able to use url helper for that, but it is obviously not working:

This is how I have set it up:

```
      @if(!url('/register'))
        <li>
          <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
        </li>
      @endif
```

Comment: can you add laravel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`request()->is()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#request-path-and-method) to detect if current URL matches string:

```
@if (request()->is('register*'))
```

Comment: in this case all routes which contains register won't show button. Be careful with this )

Comment: @dyachenko, I've added asterix to show how it works. ) Anyway I'd recommend to click the link above and read about `is()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath()` method for get current url like below way:

```
@if(Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath() != 'register')

 <li>
     <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
 </li>

@endif
```

Hope this answer will help you well!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (without remembering a lot of APIs) to do this is you add a variable in your method:

```
public function register() // if this is your page in the controller
{
  return view('register')->with('no_register_link', true);
}
```

So that, you can check it in the template:

```
@if (!$no_register_link)
<li>...template...</li>
@endif
```

In this way, you can separate the display logic and the url itself. (In case you want to ignore it also in another page.)